# TYPO3 SOLR search not working. Error in indexing

Tags: search, solr, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I'm using TYPO3 7.6.10 and solr 6.5.0

Plugin: Apache solr for TYPO3 6.1.0 Whenever I search something it says

> "**Nothing found for "here is the term I search".** "

I'm taking help from docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/solr/Backend/ConnectionManager.html. In the next step when I index in **search** module, It gives me

> "**Manual Indexing An error occurred while indexing manual from the
>   backend**".

[image: screenshot 1]

And when I click **show error** it gives

[image: screenshot 3]

I appreciate your help.

Comment: What does the log in "System" => "Log" say?

Comment: It doesn't show any error.

Comment: I can't see any error log regarding this anywhere. I've installed the **Developer's Log** plugin as well but it is also not showing any error log.

Comment: @J_Singh Did you have this issue ever solved?

Comment: Is the site protected with .htaccess ?